# PowerShell Script Bulk Rename Files with Date and Month

Tags: powershell

Does anyone know how I can change the below PowerShell script to also include month and year:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mp4 | Rename-Item -newname {“SONYA7 - “ + $_.LastWriteTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd - HH-mm-ss") + ".mp4"}
```

For example the above script will produce:

*SONYA7 - 2020-05-01 - 15-50-35.mp4*

But I need it to produce:

*SONYA7 - 2020-05-01 (May 2020).mp4*

It's probably a really a simple fix but I've tried a few different methods but all I get is error messages. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: `$_.LastWriteTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd (MMM yyyy)")`

Comment: I gave something similar a try but unfortunately I get the below error for each file:

Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At line:1 char:23
+ ... tem *.mp4 | Rename-Item -newname {“SONYA7 - “ + $_.LastWriteTime.toSt ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\mmm\... - 16-58-58.mp4:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: That is what you can expect if you have more files from the same day and you remove the time part..

Comment: Ahhh this makes sense. Never thought about that. I'll need to add the time format too. Gosh that is a long file name.I guess it's about what the client wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comments

If you want the file named `SONYA7 - 2020-05-01 (May 2020).mp4`, then use `$_.LastWriteTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd (MMM yyyy)")`.

However, as you have noticed, this will lead to name collisions, where files modified on the same day will get equal filenames. To overcome that, you need to keep the file Time part aswell.

Perhaps a format of `"yyyy-MM-dd (MMM yyyy HH-mm-ss)"` would be a better choice, although it does create long filenames..

Then, there is a *gotcha* to consider here too:
When using code like `Get-ChildItem *.mp4 | Rename-Item ...`, the Get-ChildItem cmdlet will pick up files that have already been renamed aswell, performing the operation multiple times.

To stop it from iterating already renamed files, either

- capture the collection of files from Get-ChildItem first in a variable and loop through that **OR**
- surround the Get-ChildItem part with brackets so it will finish complete before sending the items through the pipe

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.mp4' -File) | 
 Rename-Item -NewName { 'SONYA7 - {0:yyyy-MM-dd (MMM yyyy HH-mm-ss)}.mp4' -f $_.LastWriteTime }
```